# "Nullable object must have a value" when Where uses a method?

Tags: c#, linq, azure, nullable, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to run a LINQ query against an Azure DocumentDB collection. When I run my query I keep getting an `AggregateException` that contains an `InvalidOperationException` with the message:

> Nullable object must have a value

I've reduced this issue to the following (somewhat contrived) example:

When I run this code, I get the above mentioned exception thrown from the call to `ToArray()`

```
public class MyDocument { ... }

public void RunQuery()
{
    var query = documentDbClient
        .CreateDocumentQuery<MyDocument>()
        .Where(doc => GetDoc(doc) != null);
    var results = query.ToArray()
}

public MyDocument GetDoc(MyDocument myDocument)
{
    return myDocument;
}
```

In contrast, when I run the code below no exception is thrown and I get back good results from the DocumentDB collection.

```
public void RunQuery()
{
    var query = documentDbClient
        .CreateDocumentQuery<MyDocument>()
        .Where(doc => doc != null);
    var results = query.ToArray()
}
```

**Why the difference in behavior between the two code samples?**

Notes:
- While `GetDoc()` is a stand in for my more complex predicate logic, the code above reproduces the issue *exactly*. I'm not withholding any shenanigans inside `GetDoc()` or other methods :)
- The issue occurs even when `GetDoc()` is made `static`.
- Just tried to reproduce with a `List<MyDocument>` instead of  `documentDbClient` and no exception was thrown. Indicates something in the underlying data provider = Azure DocumentDB's `IDatabaseClient`.

Comment: Well, then your `GetDoc` method is the problem :). So either you show the method or we can't help you.

Comment: The GetDoc method apparently returns a non-nullable type.

Comment: I don't know  Azure DocumentDB. So this may not be an appropriate answer. But with Entity Framework that code will error out at runtime because it can't call BACK into code on the calling side (e.g. your GetDoc function). I can see any system like this having that type of problem. Perhaps it supports a delegate? e.g. Func<MyDocument> whereClause = (d) => { return d; }" where you can at least wrap your complex logic in a reusable Func.

Comment: Tx everyone :). @ckruczek `GetDoc()` is included in the question. @wicher-visser what's wrong with non-nullable? @trevor-ash I don't fully get what you're saying, perhaps you'd like to elaborate in an answer?

Comment: Is MyDocument a `struct` ?  Because in that case the parameter of GetDoc(...) is the problem. Not the return.

Comment: @henk-holterman Tx but no, sorry. `MyDocument` is a POCO.

Comment: I've edited that in.

Comment: Without seeing the real GetDoc(), my crystal ball is telling me that there is a select statement inside of that method with a .Value call on a nullable column.

Comment: @chees-burgers no funny business in my version of `GetDoc()` - The version included in the question is enough to repro the issue.

Comment: Looks like a linq provider implemented for documentdb.  That means everything before your `ToArray` call is not executed, but *interpreted* to create a call into the object store.  Your method can't be interpreted.  You're just getting a weird error message instead of a clear "you can't do that stop it"

Comment: Hey - I work on the DocumentDB team.

I can confirm Will is correct.

As for the unclear error message... there is a bug in the 1.8.x SDK that is causing the proper error message to be swallowed. This will be fixed in the upcoming 1.9.x release.

Comment: @andrew-liu many thanks. Would you like to post this as an answer? Also, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With help from @andrew-liu and @will (thanks!) I've been able to figure out that:

At the time of the call to `Where()` in my above example, the predicate inside is interpreted (rather than executed) as a LINQ expression. At the time of the call to `ToArray()` the LINQ expression is executed against the [DocumentDB .NET SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sdk-dotnet/)'s LINQ provider.

Because the SDK is not aware of my `GetDoc()` method, it throws the exception with the cryptic message *"Nullable object must have a value"*.

In v1.9 of the DocumentDB SDK for .Net the error message is much clearer. A `DocumentQueryException` is thrown with a message like *"Method "GetDoc()" is not supported"*.

You can get similar feedback from v1.8 of the SDK by invoking `ToString()` on the query like so: `query.ToString()`.